# Why are questions about design patterns opinion based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, closed-questions

This question didn't feel opinion based and the answer was EXACTLY what I was searching for.

Was there something I should have done differently?

[Design Patterns for CosmosDB and/or Graph Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61641962/design-patterns-for-cosmosdb-and-or-graph-databases)

Comment: possibly related: [Choosing the right Design Pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/227880/31260)

Comment: Interesting point, but this question is kind of the reverse. I had started implementing something, and then was looking for patterns to refine it.

Comment: The key phrase used in one of the two questions asked was "Is it appropriate..." How is that *not* asking for an opinion? Also, just because someone answered an off-topic question does not make the question on-topic.

Comment: I agree that the question is not "primarily opinion-based". You are looking for an objective, reasoned answer, ideally with citations. It seems to me that makes it suitable for Stack Overflow. I'm not a subject matter expert, so I don't quite feel comfortable overriding the community members who voted to close this, but I will say that I am uncomfortable with the closure. Perhaps this would be a better fit for [SoftwareEngineering.SE]?

Comment: I guess my take is "is it appropriate" is not really an opinion necessarily. E.g. "is it appropriate to store 1 TB of database for a real time database on a 5400 rpm drive"?

Comment: Ok, reworded it to get rid of "is it appropriate"

Comment: I'm going to take your rewording as my justification to re-open this question.  As I noted  in the edit summary, I removed the Python tag because I don't see anything related to Python in the question. (It isn't important that you happen to be using Python in order to interact with your database. Tags should describe the question itself, not the environment/milieu.) If I'm missing something due to my lack of domain knowledge, feel free to reinstate the tag. (But you probably want to use the generic [python] tag, not a version-specific tag, since this definitely isn't version-specific.)

Comment: Thanks! I'd love to be better at SO, if there's anything I can do to not make this mistake again in the future, I'd love to hear about it.